# Miss charset on upload to online server

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, upload, ansi

I have a problem with the charset of my files.

I create the documents in localhost by setting the charset to UFT8 (wb), but when uploading to the online server the charset is changed to ANSI.

I use Filezilla and the provider is Kinghost.

**Update**: I switched to binary transfer. Apparently it did not work. See the configuration in the image below. In the second image, the encoding in notepad.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you uploading the files using ASCII or Binary as the transfer type? You should be using the latter if you don't want the files altered

Comment: Your screenshot shows a PHP file being edited. Double check your FileZilla configuration to see if it auomatically switches back to ASCII for PHP instead of using Binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filezilla's transfer mode must be binary so that the file does not have its edited charset.

But my problem was having created the files in ANSI. When creating the files we must choose UTF-8 without BOM.